# apt-cacher cleanup is taking too long

Tags: debian

On my Debian6 I have **apt-cacher** installed and running correctly.

Every day the current task is run **/etc/cron.daily/apt-cacher:
    #!/bin/sh

```
# Only do anything if apt-cacher is actually installed
if [ ! -x /usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher.pl ]; then
  exit 0
fi

# Run the report generator
/usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-report.pl

# Run the cache cleaner
# Add -v to get an email showing what the script has done
# Add -p to use the experimental pdiff code
/usr/share/apt-cacher/apt-cacher-cleanup.pl -f
```

The script **apt-cacher-cleanup.pl** is taking more than 1 hour to complete and while it's running, other it looks like other machines are pending (kind of frozen).

I used the arg "-v" to receive an email, and everything looks fine. I can see at the end of the email:
    Found 134105 valid file entries

1) Is it normal that the cleanup scrit is taking that much time?

2) What is "134105 valid file entries"? I only have 1297 files in my cache folder.

3) Should I delete the cache folder, so it will re-download only the necessary packages?

Thanks

** EDIT
There is no 134105 packages. I'm not sure why I have this number on this email. In the folder **/var/cache/apt_cacher/packages**, I have 1297, which seems to be more reasonable.

** EDIT2
Sometime **apt-cacher-cleanup.pl** is taking only 10min and no frozen machines.

Comment: Can't you simply use `apt-get clean` ?

Comment: In my understanding, "apt-get clean" will clean packages used by the machine, but it won't affect cache packages by apt-cacher.